# WCF Client Certificate stopped working

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, ssl, iis

After following a few MSDN articles I had client certificates and user name passwords working for my WCF service.  The client required a certificate and a username and password to access my service.

Recently, the certificate stopped working, I can access the service without supplying the client certificate. I am using SOAP UI to test the client.  Normally I have to add the client cert to the key store and then specify which key to use for the request.

Recently I set up a test and I didn't have to supply the client cert.  Nothing in my conifg changed.  Do I have the set up properly?

Thank you.

My Binding Config:

```
 <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" />

          </security>

        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
```

My Service:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="APIServiceBehaviour" name="Service">
        <endpoint address="api" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding" name="soap-api" bindingNamespace="https://myserver.com" contract="IAIService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://myserver.com" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
```

The Behavior:

```
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="MyAuthorizationPolicy,MyProject" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>

      <serviceCredentials>

        <serviceCertificate findValue="tempSClient" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" includeWindowsGroups="false" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyProject.UserAuth,MyProject" />
      </serviceCredentials>

    </behavior>
```

Comment: Why do you think it worked before?

Comment: I was getting 403 error.  When I added the client cert, it would let me in to authenticate using web service security

Comment: How does `MyProject.UserAuth` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

The certificates have an expiration date.
Did you check you certificate in certmgr.msc ?

Comment: Yes.  The certs are ok.